# RabbitMQ: new mail notification model

Tags: rabbitmq

I am writing a webmail server. I use websockets for new mail notifications to the clients.

When an new email arrives at the server I want to notify all the web-clients for that specific use. I.e. a user may have multiple browser windows open.

Can you advise how I can  model this with rabbitmq?

What I though was either create one fan out exchange per user, which doesn’t sound resource efficient, or have a single fan out exchange and all clients connect to that, so all client receive all email notifications, which doesn’t sound right either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to send all the mails that arrive at the webmail server to all the clients who are subscribed to it, i think that fanout is the better message exchange option. A fanout exchange routes messages to all of the queues that are bound to it. I you want to send a particular mail to a particular users use `direct`.

[image: direct]

In this setup, we can see the direct exchange X with two queues bound to it. The first queue is bound with binding key orange, and the second has two bindings, one with binding key black and the other one with green.

In such a setup a message published to the exchange with a routing key orange will be routed to queue Q1. Messages with a routing key of black or green will go to Q2. All other messages will be discarded.

multiple-binding(same as that of fanout)

[image: multiple-binding]

it is perfectly legal to bind multiple queues with the same binding key. In our example we could add a binding between X and Q1 with binding key black. In that case, the direct exchange will behave like fanout and will broadcast the message to all the matching queues. A message with routing key black will be delivered to both Q1 and Q2.

Comment: So I will have to have an exchange per user-id, right?

Comment: no need to use user-id because you want to send all the mails to every one. If you want to send a particular mail to a specific user then the strategy should be changed

Comment: I want to send each mail to all the clients of that user. I.e. I have multiple users and each user has multiple clients. I wouldn’t like the clients of user B to be notified for the messages of user A.

Comment: ok. If this is your requirement, then you can use either `direct` or `topic` exchange

Comment: Right; `direct` is exactly what I wanted. Great, thanks a lot.